# jQuery extension function that returns jQuery stack to way it was before function was called

Tags: jquery

I would like to create an jQuery extension method called `scope()` that has TypeScript signature `scope(fn: (jq: JQuery) => void)`. That would return jQuery stack like it was before function was called, without needing `end()` calls

Currently I have this kind of code.

```
$table
    .children("tbody")
    .find(getSelector("delete")).closest("td").hide().end().end()
    .find(getSelector("select")).closest("td").show().end().end()
    .children(getSelector("row")).addClass("info").end()
    .end()
    .append(this.get("remind-template").html())
    .find(getSelector("remind-message")).focus();
```

I would like to create extension method that would make it look like this

```
$table
    .scope(x => x
        .children("tbody")
        .scope(y => y.find(getSelector("delete")).closest("td").hide())
        .scope(y => y.find(getSelector("select")).closest("td").show())
        .children(getSelector("row")).addClass("info")
    )
    .append(this.get("remind-template").html())
    .find(getSelector("remind-message")).focus();
```

What's the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! :)

```
$.fn.scope = function (fn) {
  fn($(this));
  return this;
}
```

and typing

```
scope(fn: (jq: JQuery) => void): JQuery;
```